# Dynamically extract comments from files using cat

Tags: shell, grep, cat

I have a bunch of bash files, and each have a function and a comment block that describes that function.

Example:

`~/helpers/plugins/test-util.bash`

```
# Function Name: test_util
#
# Description: .....

function test() ....
```

I have a help function that will be triggered when i pass `--help` parameter my function. The help is specific for each function name.

Function names contain `_` in them, while the filenames have `-` instead.
Example: `test-util.bash` is the filename while the function that will be passed will be called `test_util`

The command i execute looks like:

`helpers test_util --help`

This will execute the test_util function in the location `~/helpers/plugins/test-util.bash`

Question:

I want to dynamically show the comments attached in each file. What i do is:

1- Construct the correct file name from the passed function name using `FILENAME= echo "~/helpers/plugins/${1}.bash" | tr '_' '-'` to replace any underscores

2- I extract the comments using `cat $FILENAME | grep '#' | cut -c 2- | tail -n +3`

Now, my problem is with the cat statement as i am passing the filename as a variable that i pass to the function and i dont seem to get this working.

The command works fine in terminal if i am passing the filename directly to the cat command.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `FILENAME="$(echo ... | tr ...)"` surely?

Comment: @AlexP well it works .. anything wrong in that ?

Comment: Ah I see, you had backticks which got eaten by the formatting... Try adding an `echo FILENAME="\"$FILENAME\""` just before the `cat` command, to see what the value of FILENAME is.

Comment: @AlexP i already did and its indeed a correct filepath with the replaced `-`

Comment: @AlexP actually its not working .. the echo i was getting was from assignment .. it seems that there is something wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your assignment really is

```
FILENAME= echo "~/helpers/plugins/${1}.bash" | tr '_' '-'
```

as it appears in the question, then this is incorrect. The correct form is

```
FILENAME="$(echo "~/helpers/plugins/${1}.bash" | tr '_' '-')"
```

The command as it appears in the question means to run `echo ... | tr ...` with an empty variable named `FILENAME` in the environment.